# Find Jordan normal form and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $$A=M(\varphi)^{st}_{st}={\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\-4&-4&-2\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}}$$ and $ \varphi: \mathbb R^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{3}$. Find the Jordan normal form $J_{A}$ for the matrix $A$ and a basis $X$ for the endomorphism $\varphi$ such that $J_{A}=M(\varphi)^{X}_{X}$.

I did this task but unfortunately my basis is not correct and I do not know where I'm making a mistake.

**My try:**

The appointment of $ J_ {A} $ is clear to me, so I will write only the result:
$$J_{A}={\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}}$$Then I am trying to find basis:

$$(A+2I)^{2}={\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}}$$

$$\alpha_{2} \in \ker(\varphi+2id)^{2}- \ker(\varphi +2id)$$

$$\ker(\varphi+2id)^{2}=\mathbb R^{3}$$

$$\ker(\varphi+2id)=lin\left\{(1,-2,0),(0,-1,1)\right\}$$

From the above conclusions I think that I can take:

$$\alpha_{2}=(0,1,0)$$

$$\alpha_{1}=(\varphi+2id)(\alpha_{2})=(1,-2,0)$$

As $\alpha_{3}$ I choose a linearly independent vector and I have for example:

$$\alpha_{3}=(0,0,1)$$

So my basis is:

$$X=\left\{(1,-2,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\right\}$$
I know that basis can be different. That's why I checked my answer: 
$$J_{A}=M(\varphi)_{X}^{X}=M(id)^{X}_{st}M(\varphi)^{st}_{st}M(id)^{st}_{X}$$ From my basis I have: $$M(id)^{st}_{X}={\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-2&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}}$$Then I made a multiplication: $$M(id)^{X}_{st}M(\varphi)^{st}_{st}M(id)^{st}_{X}$$ and I get: $${\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&1\\0&-2&0\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}}$$Of course this is not equal $J_{A}$ so I know that I have a mistake.
I would like to add that it is very strange for me that when I was curiosity I changed the vector $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ then I get $J_{A}$. However by my calculation I can't do it.

Can you help me and say where I am doing something wrong? I suspect that I make some mistake in determining $ \alpha_{2} $ but I still do not realize what.

Comment: Why do you believe that your answer is incorrect? In general, if someone tells you they've computed a basis for one of these normal form problems, do you know how to check whether they're answer is correct? Have you done this check on your own answer?

Comment: @GregMartin I edited my post and I explained why I know that I have a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've successfully obtained the data of $A$ and its Jordan form $J$ as
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-4 & -4 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right] & J &= \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Note that our table of eigenvalues is
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\lambda & \operatorname{am}_A(\lambda) & \operatorname{gm}_A(\lambda) \\ \hline
-2 & 3 & 2
\end{array}
$$
Here, $\operatorname{am}_A(-2)$ is the *algebraic multiplicity* of $-2$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ (the number of times $-2$ appears on the diagonal of $J$) and $\operatorname{gm}_A(-2)$ is the *geometric multiplicity* (the number of Jordan blocks in $J$ corresponding to $-2$).

Let's find the change of basis matrix using [this algorithm](https://math.rice.edu/~friedl/math355_fall04/Jordan.pdf) described by Stefan Friedl.

First, we compute the numbers
$$
d_k = \operatorname{nullity}((A+2\cdot I)^k)-\operatorname{nullity}((A+2\cdot I)^{k-1})
$$
for $1\leq k\leq\operatorname{gm}_A(-2)=2$. Computing these numbers gives
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= 2 & d_2 &= 1
\end{align*}
We use these numbers to construct a diagram 
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\Box & \Box \\
\Box 
\end{array}
$$
According to our algorithm, we start at the bottom of this diagram and fill the boxes in row $k$ with linearly independent vectors that belong to $\operatorname{Null}((A+2\,I)^k)$ but not $\operatorname{Null}((A+2\,I)^{k-1})$. As soon as a box is filled with a vector $\vec{v}$, we fill the box above with $(A+2\,I)\vec{v}$.

By noting that 
\begin{align*}
A+2\,I &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
-4 & -2 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] & (A+2\,I)^2 &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
we see that our diagram can take the form
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\fbox{$\left\langle2,\,-4,\,0\right\rangle$} & \fbox{$\left\langle0,\,1,\,-1\right\rangle$}\\
\fbox{$\left\langle1,\,0,\,0\right\rangle$}
\end{array}
$$
This defines our change of basis matrix $P$ as
$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can check our work by verifying that $A=PJP^{-1}$. Indeed, we have
$$
\overset{A}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-4 & -4 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right]}
=
\overset{P}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{J}{\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{P^{-1}}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]}
$$

Comment: I really thank you for your work but I need also knowledge why my sollution has a mistake because I think it is good to know different methods but also what mistakes are made in your ideas. Do you have anything to say, what could have happened in my way?

Comment: If you compare the two solutions, you should be able to see where our methods diverge.